# How to match text which the part of it is already matched previous?

Tags: regex

I have a string like `aaa**b***c****ddd`, and I want to get a sequence of matched text of pattern `[^*]\*+[^*]`, which should I thank be `[a**b, b***c, c***d]`. However, when I test this in text editor like vim or emacs, the second (`b***c`) is not matched.

```
aaa**b***c***ddd
  |--|   |---|
  first  third
     |---|
     second, which I think should be matched but not
```

How should I modify the regular expression to match the second?

Comment: As far as I know a regex always "consumes" each character once. So there is probably no solution to this except matching the string twice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, the trick consists to put all in a capturing group inside a lookahead to allow overlapping results:

```
(?=([^*]\*+[^*]))
```

But you can't use this do to replacements since this pattern matches nothing. (or perhaps if you can get the capture group length and the current offset)

EDIT:

it seems to be possible to obtain the capture group length with vim with `strlen(submatch(1))`

Comment: +1 I was going to post this but was not sure of the language he was using.

Answer (score 1):

@CommuSoft is correct. One way to approach this problem would be to match the whole string against this regex and then the second time around, you match this regex against the substring that starts at (index_of_first_previous_match + 1) until the end of the string. Hope that is clear.

So if the index of your first match above (a**b) was 2. Then the new substring that you match against the regex the second time should start from index 3 till the end of the string. This will give you the two results.

However, Casimir's answer is much simpler.